# What version of xdebug do you need for php 5.3.5?

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

I'm trying to get xdebug working with netbeans and php 5.3.5 but with no luck.  I'm wondering if the versions of xdebug and php aren't compatible?

Comment: the dll I'm using for xdebug is : php_xdebug-2.1.0-5.3-vc9.dll

Comment: You can check if the xdebug extension is actually activated with `<? phpinfo(); ?>`

Answer (score 1):

XDebug 2.1.0 should be working. Are you getting any errors?

Downloads URL: http://www.xdebug.org/download.php

Answer (score 0):

You can try those:
http://www.xdebug.org/files/php_xdebug-2.1.0-5.3-vc6-nts.dll
http://www.xdebug.org/files/php_xdebug-2.1.0-5.3-vc6.dll
Both for 32 bit platform